# Abort trap: 6 Swift 4.2 Xcode Error on Release

Tags: iphone, swift4, xcode10

I got this error only when I build the project in for **archive** the application install normally in my iPhone.

Some Help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by changing the production release to **-Onone**

[image]

and changing release to **DWARF**

[image]

In the Build setting.